# How to calculate number of records of each month?

Tags: mysql

I want to calculate number of records in each month of the year.

```
select count(t2.user) as total, concat(YEAR(t2.docdate), '-', MONTH(t2.docdate)) as date

from tbl1 t1
LEFT JOIN tbl2 t2 ON(...)

WHERE

AND t2.docdate BETWEEN '2018-10-01' AND '2019-03-25'

GROUP BY MONTH(t2.docdate)

total docdate
```

But my result is coming incorrect.

```
18    2018-12-12
93    2018-12-12
51    2018-11-18
12    2018-11-07
13    2018-11-03
```

Comment: What is the purpose of your `tbl1.t1` ? It wasn't in anywhere..

Comment: I do join from this table

Answer (score 3):

You need to group by the same field you include in your select statement:

```
select count(t2.user) as total, concat(YEAR(t2.docdate), '-', MONTH(t2.docdate)) as date    
from tbl1 t1
LEFT JOIN tbl2 t2 ON(...)

WHERE

AND t2.docdate BETWEEN '2018-10-01' AND '2019-03-25'

GROUP BY concat(YEAR(t2.docdate), '-', MONTH(t2.docdate))
```

Comment: How can I add order by so that my data is based on docdate. ... 2018-01, 2018-02.... now it is not sorted

Comment: I did ORDER BY concat(YEAR(t2.docdate), '-', MONTH(t2.docdate)) But not working

Answer (score 1):

try like below by using dateformat

```
  select count(t2.user) as total, 
  DATE_FORMAT(t2.docdate,'%Y-%m') as date    
 from  tbl2  t2
 LEFT JOIN tbl1 t1 ON(...)    
 WHERE    
 t2.docdate BETWEEN '2018-10-01' AND '2019-03-25'    
 GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(t2.docdate,'%Y-%m')
```

and it seems to me you need to use table2 as left table rather than table1